# Create output script file of FTP upload

Tags: powershell, ftp

I have a script that uploads files to FTP servers, I have a list of servers IP `$FTPServer` and directory from files are uploaded `\Upload`. It uses the [PSFTP module](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-FTP-Client-db6fe0cb).

Here is my code of reading file `$item` and uploading to IP `$line`:

```
foreach ($line in $FTPServer)
{
    foreach ($item in (Get-ChildItem .\Upload))
    {
        Start-Transcript -Path $results
        Write-Host -Object "ftp url: $line" 
        Set-FTPConnection -Credentials $FTPCredential -Server $line -Session MySession -UsePassive 
        $Session = Get-FTPConnection -Session MySession 
        Write-Host -Object "Uploading $item..."
        Add-FTPItem -Session $Session -Path $FTPPlace -LocalPath .\Upload\$item -Confirm:$false
        Stop-Transcript
    }
}
```

The problem is, sometimes not all files can be upload or someone server is down. Therefore there is need to save results of uploading. I think about something like table which would be stored in `logs.txt` and looks like that:

```
FTP Server   File       Connected   Uploaded
----------   ---------  --------    --------
192.168.1.2  test.txt   OK          OK #when connected and uploaded file
192.168.1.2  conf.dll   OK          FAIL #when connected but did not upload
192.168.1.20 test.txt   FAIL        FAIL #when did not connect and no uploaded
```

I was thinking about hash table:

```
$array = $line, $item, $array[2], $array[3]
$FailTable=New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{"FTP Server"=$array[0]; "File"=$array[1];"Connected"=$array[2];"Uploaded"=$array[3]})
$FailTable|Out-File '.\stats.txt'
```

But I don't know how to put there status of connections and uploads to `$array[2]` and `$array[3]`
I will glad for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You could build the array as a combination of server and file name, and then store the results **pass**, **fail**, **etc**.

So, your has table for:

```
192.168.1.2  test.txt   OK          OK #when connected and uploaded file
192.168.1.2  conf.dll   OK          FAIL #when connected but did not upload
192.168.1.20 test.txt   FAIL        FAIL #when did not connect and no uploaded
```

would look like:

```
"192.168.1.2\test.txt","OK"
"192.168.1.2\conf.dll","OK"
"192.168.1.20\test.txt","FAIL"
```

If you used a non-allowable character (say `*` between the IP and the name, you could then do a `split("*")` to break them back apart.

Depending on the module your using for FTP, you might be able to say:

```
$results = Add-FTPItem -Session $Session -Path $FTPPlace -LocalPath .\Upload\$item -Confirm:$false
```

and then look at the value of `$results` to see if there were issues(maybe?)

Answer (score -1):

I add answer to my own question yesterday:

> I have made a ftp script file, with ftp.ini file.
>   The file was in  c:\hotbox\ftpbat.bat

I was in wrong directory. The program worked fine, but I run the bat-program in different index of drive. I was testing it in my VB6-index

Sorry.